# Cornered by const: std::map::find() const overload

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, const-correctness

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <map>

class C {
public:
    C() {}

    const int& f(const int& x) const
    {
        // Error: cannot cast const int* to int* const
        return myMap.find(&x)->second;

        // With a const_cast works:
        //return myMap.find(const_cast<int* const>(&x))->second;
    }

    std::map<int*, int> myMap;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x = 0;

    C c;
    c.f(x);

    return 0;
}
```

The error in `f()` is caused by the const overload of map's `find()` taking a `const KeyType&`.  Because the key type of the map is `int*`, this turns in to `int* const`.  `f()` takes a `const int&` parameter, which is correct because the parameter is never modified.

Unfortunately this ends up in trying to cast a `const int*` to a `int* const`, which loses the const qualifier on the int and won't compile.

This is kind of irritating because the parameter definitely isn't ever modified - it's just used for a find() - but I still need to `const_cast` it.

Is there a way to write `f()` without the `const_cast`?

Comment: This is rather unusual:  why are you using pointers as map keys?

Comment: In my applications the keys need to be references to heavyweight objects, and you can't use a reference as a map key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real question is: why isn't the index of the map a pointer
to const?  (Supposing, of course, that it should be a pointer.)
Do you really want to be able to modify the index via something
like `*myMap.find(&x)->first = xxx`; I would say that that is
quite unusual, given that you already have a pointer to the
object.

Answer (score 7):

You can just change the type of the `map` to `std::map<const int*, int>`; I question whether you need pointers as keys in the first place, though. As James points out, the key type should be `const int*` because you never intend to modify the referent via the `map`. If you did, I'd be even more worried.